# Command host with awk

Tags: shell, script

Please, why "echo" instruction:

```
iphost="$(ssh root@$machine -x "host $machine | awk '/has address/ { print $4 }'")"
echo $iphost
```

display:

```
g-3.xx.yyy.zz has address 172.16.65.35
```

instead of:

```
172.16.65.35
```

?

Thank you so much for help.

Best Regards.

Comment: is it possible for  example to 172.16.65.35 from the variable iphost ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use escape sequence backslash(\) inside awk command as below. Since you use the command inside double quotes the variables will be resolved before executing. So it will try to understand $4 as a system variable and try to resolve it. If you use escape sequence backslash it will retain the $4 to the awk command.

```
iphost="$(ssh root@$machine -x "host $machine | awk '/has address/ { print \$4 }'")"
echo $iphost
```

Comment: yeah! \$4     Thank you so much for help :) Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in ~/.bashrc or similar

```
export iphost="$(echo $SSH_CLIENT | awk '{print $1}')"
```

Comment: Sorry are you trying to find the IP address of `machine` from local, or find IP of local from `machine`?  My answer assumed the later.  You could always tack `| sed 's/.*has\ address\ //'` to the end of your `iphost` definition.  Not elegant since we are piping `awk` and `sed` but I'm a hacker, not a pro!